# Reductions: Turing Machines

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Good morning,

I am really lost in this exercise. I know what they are asking for, but I cannot get a way to solve it or to find a proper defition for each case in order to prove the reduction. Here's the statement.

Consider the following variations of INDEPENDENT SET:

$A$:

**input**: an encoding $\lfloor{G, k, u}\rfloor$, where $G = (V, E)$ is a graph, $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $u \in V$.

**question**: does $G$ have an independent set $X$ of size $k$ such that $u \in X$?

$C:$

**input**: an encoding $\lfloor{G, k}\rfloor$ of a graph $G$ and a natural number $k \ge 1$.

**question**: does $G$ have two distinct independent sets of size $k$?

a) Show that $A \le_{P}$ INDEPENDENT SET.

b) Show that INDEPENDENT SET $\le_{P} A$.

c) Show that INDEPENDENT SET $\le_{P} C$.

Need to say: If $G = (V, E)$ is a graph and $X \subseteq V$, we say that $X$ is an INDEPENDENT SET if no edge of $G$ connects two vertices of $X$.

Thank you all!

Comment: Totally off topic: But your profile picture is hilarious.

Comment: I know, Euler rocks!

Comment: What is the problem "INDEPENDENT SET"? Also, by "distinct" I think you mean "disjoint" in $C$.

Comment: In all these cases, you will need to show: there is a way to take an instance of the problem you are reducing **from**, and change that into an instance of the problem you are reducing **to**, so that the new instance gives the same answer from the problem you are reducing to that the old instance did for the problem you are reducing from. (E.g. if you are proving $A \leq_P B$ you are reducing from $A$ to $B$.) Also, because you are looking at polynomial-time reductions, you need to verify that the algorithm to compute the new instance from the old one runs in polynomial time.